# Thunderbird IMAP - Read: receipts being moved

Tags: imap, thunderbird

Thunderbird 3 insists on moving message receipts (with the subject "Read:") into the Sent folder. This never happened with any other client I've used with this IMAP server. I can't find anything about this behavior in Thunderbird's settings?

To clarify, if I manually move them back to Inbox using another client, they stay. As soon as I open/resync Thunderbird, they all appear back in the Sent folder (they appear there to all clients).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this has changed from Thunderbird 3.0, but in 8.0 (which isn't all that much newer)

Tools / Options
Advanced
General tab
There's a Return Receipts... button
In that dialog, there's an option

When a receipt arrives:

- Leave it in my Inbox
- Move it to my Sent folder